# java.lang.NullPointerException org.red5.logging.LoggerContextFilter.doFilter(LoggerContextFilter

Tags: red5, red5pro

i get the following error in RED5 when i use, LoggerContextFilter

Any idea what I might be doing wrong, using RED5 1.0.7 version

filter:

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>LoggerContextFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.red5.logging.LoggerContextFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>LoggerContextFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Error:

```
**java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.red5.logging.LoggerContextFilter.doFilter(LoggerContextFilter.java:63)**
```

Answer (score 0):

All of my webapps have this in the web.xml

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.red5.logging.ContextLoggingListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
    <filter-name>LoggerContextFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.red5.logging.LoggerContextFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>LoggerContextFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

I think you're just missing the listener.

Comment: i have tried springmvc sample as it is with the listner above you have listed. but it still gave me the NPE

Comment: error is thrown at following line context filter
LoggingContextSelector selector = (LoggingContextSelector) Red5LoggerFactory.getContextSelector();
        LoggerContext ctx = selector.getLoggerContext(contextName);

Comment: error is coming from this 'useLogBack' always tends false in Red5LoggerFactory 

public static ContextSelector getContextSelector() {
        if (useLogback) {..
        }
        return null;
    }

Comment: That property should be true by default, are you setting it to false?

Comment: nope I am not touching that anywhere, but i have deployed hlsplugin in the server